# What web browsers support a feature similar to Chrome's People?

Tags: web-browser

Chrome comes with a built-in feature "People" to allow the user to create different browser profiles for different persons.

[image: Chrome interface showing users's profile and a button 'Manage people']

Are there other web browsers that provide a similar feature?

Comment: What Os must it run on? Any price limit in case of paid solutions? Any other features it should support which might not be common (well, display ing web pages should be common enough of course – but e.g. supporting addons is not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Vivaldi](http://vivaldi.com) Browser, just tape "vivaldi://user-manager" in the url bar

[image: Vivaldi user manager interface]

Hope its help you :)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible in firefox with the profile manager [see details](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).
You might use some firefox extensions like **multifox** to make it easyer

Other browsers built with blink engine are able to do that thanks to the option `--user-data-dir` [details](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). 
For instance as from **opera** version 15 you can start it from the cli by specifying a profile directory:

```
opera --user-data-dir="/tmp/myprofile"
```